# Rails 4: 2 ways has_many :through with polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

**EDIT**

I implemented a solution that seems to work. It's a bit of black magic and I believe it's application specific, so I believe it's not useful for the community to post it here. However I could do so if someone really want to see it.

--

I got `User` and `Agency` models and I am trying to find out how to set-up a `Partnership` model that would link users and agency, given:

- A user can be partner with agencies and other users
- A agency can be partner with users and other agencies

Later on I need to be able to call `user.partners` and get the whole list of users and agencies partner of this `user` (same goes for `agency`)

I am trying to set-up a has_many through with polymorphic but I get confused. any hint appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably need 4 fields in this partnership model, which would make it impossible I believe to use rails polymorphic behavior.  There would be a partner_1_id, as well as partner_2_id.  Then you'd need a partner_type:string or partner_type:integer column for each to determine what kind of relationship it's going to be.

You could query this by having a method in the user/agency model saying something like.

find all partnerships where partner_1_id or partner_2_id = your id, and the partner_type for that = your class.

edit: so basically, you'd need to write your own partners method in the agency and user class to just create the query.  Rails isn't going to be able to do this for you here.

Comment: Yep, for the meantime that's exactly what I'm doing. I still wonder if someone can come up with a better solution